# Wordpress site cant get more white padding under my header

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I cant seem to figure out how to edit the style sheet in order to get 20px more of white space under the health forge image without moving the category link button.  Here is the page. https://www.healthyforge.com/

I tried adding margin to the main-content class but that doesnt give me the white color, it just moves everything down like i want but adds a gray bar of color into the margin spacing.

**EDIT:**  I have sticky nav plugin turned off right now.  but with it turned on, when i scroll the nav bar sticks and is as skinny as the image height.  So I dont think I can add anything to the image or Header element.

Comment: Add `margin-bottom: 20px;` to the `custom-logo-link` class

Comment: Perfect. Except i want to use sticky nav and when scrolling I want the nav to be as thin as image itself.  I think that solution will make my sticky nav scroll bar bigger.  I turned it off for now.

Comment: If you don't want to touch anything in the header, adding `padding-top: 20px;` to the `site-content` class will shift everything in the page proper down by 20px. If you don't want a 20px gap between the vertical divider and the header, instead modify `#main` from `padding-top: 50px` to `padding-top: 70px`.

Comment: I really want to up vote you just for trying.  But i need white space, white color.  Those solutions add a gray color.  Some how i need to move the lip between the White and gray down 20px; Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using? In Firefox 62 (Linux), adding the padding in dev tools adds white spacing not grey spacing. Perhaps you need to add `background-color: white;` to `.site-content` or `#main`?

Comment: Im using the Chrome browser.